Tailwind border shows colors wrong with gradient
I have a <div class="hover:shadow-primary/25 hover:border-primary box-border flex h-full flex-col justify-center rounded-2xl border-4 border-transparent bg-gradient-to-br from-[#180042] via-[#2e017d] to-purple-900 p-20 text-white shadow-xl duration-100 ease-in-out hover:border-4 lg:col-span-2 lg:row-span-2 lg:bg-gradient-to-br"></div>
As you can see there is a weird color shift at the borders. I have a transparent border to avoid content shifting when I hover over it.


How can I either avoid the shifting of content when I hover the div or avoid the color shifting at the border?

You could consider reworking the background gradient such that it covers the border box size of the element. This involves moving its "origin" point to the top-left corner and increasing its size by the border width on all four sides:


tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: 'red',
      },
    },
  },
}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div class="
  hover:shadow-primary/25 hover:border-primary box-border flex h-full flex-col justify-center rounded-2xl border-4 border-transparent bg-gradient-to-br from-[#180042] via-[#2e017d] to-purple-900 p-20 text-white shadow-xl duration-100 ease-in-out hover:border-4 lg:col-span-2 lg:row-span-2 lg:bg-gradient-to-br
  bg-[length:calc(100%+(theme(borderWidth.4)*2))_calc(100%+(theme(borderWidth.4)*2))]
  bg-[position:calc(theme(borderWidth.4)*-1)_calc(theme(borderWidth.4)*-1)]
">Foo</div>



Alternatively, you could also consider using Tailwind's ring-* set of utilities to draw the border on hover:


tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: 'red',
      },
    },
  },
}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div class="
  hover:shadow-primary/25 box-border flex h-full flex-col justify-center rounded-2xl bg-gradient-to-br from-[#180042] via-[#2e017d] to-purple-900 p-20 text-white shadow-xl duration-100 ease-in-out lg:col-span-2 lg:row-span-2 lg:bg-gradient-to-br
  hover:ring-primary hover:ring-inset hover:ring-4
">Foo</div>




Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for, Cheers!
